# Create user defined file output location for geoprocessing on ArcGIS for Server 10.3

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-10.3, geoprocessing-service

I am working on a geoprocessing service  that allows a user to interactively select shapes and then download a .dbf file of the selected shapes.  The tool was created in modelbuilder and uses the copy rows tool to create the dbf file.

The part I cannot figure out is how to allow the user to select the output folder, as I need to fill in the output path parameter in ArcMap.  When I upload the service definition from the results window, the file path gets hardcoded into the tool and is not exposed to the user.

Any leads on where to look? My google-fu has been an abysmal failure.

Comment: How can you download a .dbf of a shape? Please edit the question to contain more information about the language in which you are programming and the code itself, and it would be more likely that someone could help you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to edit the Data Type of your Output Folder:
Right-click on your Toolbox (ArcMap) > **Properties > Parameters**. 
Probably you selected the Data Type "Folder" for your output location. There seems to be a bug. Use "String" instead. It should work just fine.